# How to resize the height of Safari's Web Inspector pane?

Tags: macos, browser, safari, web-inspector

Does anyone know how to set the height of Safari's Web Inspector? It takes up about 75% of my browser window, so I have to resize it manually each time. Here's a screenshot showing the problem: http://cl.ly/1W33123t1U0k101r2g00

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,
For me, Chrome is not an option, and there is a solution:
i was having the same problem and found that, if i did exactly the following procedure, i managed to set the height of the '**docked**' Inspector:

- Open any web page
- Call the Inspector (Command-Option-I)
- **Undock** the Inspector by clicking the dock/undock icon
- Change its **Undocked** height *and* width to roughly a height that you would like when it is docked, and roughly the same width as your browser window; make sure to change its position too (move it a little in any direction to make sure all params are recorded)
- Close the **Undocked** Inspector
- Call the Inspector again (Command-Option-I --hasn't changed)
- Dock the Inspector
- Quit Safari.

That should now stick
Launch Safari and enjoy your new **docked** Inspector's window height..

Basically, the height of the docked Inspector is about the same as that of the undocked Inspector....

Strangely, i couldn't find the preference in the com.apple.Safari.plist file...
i thought it might be the variable:

```
NSWindow Frame Web Inspector 2
```

but changing its values did not have any effect (i think that the values linked to that variable are, in order:

```
(left, bottom, width, height, 0, 0, available-width, available-height)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can do about it is using chrome instead of safari. This issue has been detected since safari 5.0 . It was even worse before, because whenever you opened web inspector it opened in an independent window. I think it will probably be fixed in the next version of safari.